# Batch file to "call" a batch file with a pause or "wait"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that "calls" another batch file, but I need to "wait" before it proceeds. How can I make this happen?

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B25\DSUninstall.bat" (
echo Catia PLM-ex V5-6R2015 needs to be removed %DATE% %TIME% >>"C:\catiaV5-6R2015.txt"
call "C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B25\DSUninstall.bat"
echo Catia PLM-ex V5-6R2015 has been removed %DATE% %TIME% >>"C:\catiaV5-6R2015.txt"
exit
) else (
echo Catia PLM-ex V5-6R2015 is not installed. %DATE% %TIME% >>"C:\catiaV5-6R2015.txt"
exit
)
```

I have tried `start /wait` instead of `call` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `call` does wait for the batch file you called to complete before continuing.  Are you sure that "DSUninstall.bat" isn't launching a program in the background and returning early?

Comment: Could be I will have to check on that. Didn't make the `DSUnistall.bat` I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a

```
timeout /t n >nul
```

instruction before the call, where `n` is the number of seconds to wait.

---

`Delayed Expansion` strikes again!

Easy solution:

```
CALL echo Catia PLM-ex V5-6R2015 has been removed %%DATE%% %%TIME%% >>"C:\catiaV5-6R2015.txt"
```

Note the `CALL` and the doubling of `%`. This executes the `echo` in a subprocedure, passing `%DATE%` hence reporting the *current* date/time.

See many articles on `delayed expansion` by using the `search` facility.

Comment: That would work if I knew how many seconds it will take for the `call "C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B25\DSUninstall.bat"` to complete.

Comment: Ah - so your *actual* problem is that the date/time reported to the file did not change and it appears that the timestamp before and after the `call` are the same?

Comment: Yes, but @indiv above mentioned that `DSUninstall.bat` it might be returning early. I need to check that.

Comment: @Eric, Yes an early return is still a possibility, but I think if you are just seeing the same timestamp before and after in the log file, Magoo has the correct solution in the updated answer.